# Motivation for predicate logic.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I am studying  predicate logic,I came across this para-

> Propositional logic, studied in Sections 1.1–1.3, cannot adequately express the meaning of all statements in mathematics and in natural language.
>
> For example, suppose that we know that
>   “Every computer connected to the university network is functioning properly.”
>
> No rules of propositional logic allow us to conclude the truth of the statement “MATH3 is functioning properly",where MATH3 is one of the computers connected to the university network.

This is supposed to illustrate the motivation for predicate logic.

*However,we can interpret the given statement as the conjunction of statements of the form "MATHx is connected to the university network and is working properly"*.

As this statement is true and is a conjunction the individual propositions have to be true;in terms of MATH3 too.

*So propositional logic expresses the meaning of the statement adequately and we have also used the rules of propositional logic to conclude the truth about MATH3 contrary to whats been stated*.

What am I missing?I have gone through the notes by Stephen Simpson and Wikipedia but they proved inadequate.

Comment: You are correct that if you wished to use propositional logic to capture the meaning of *this particular sentence* as the conjunction of a **finite** number of sentences, each expressing the proper functioning of a computer connected to the network, you could do so (supposing you had this extra information). But you won't be able to handle cases of infinite conjunction. Consider a mathematical example (which is what predicate logic was invented to help formalize): "every prime greater than $2$ is odd" can't be captured in propositional logic as a conjunction of a finite number of sentences.

Comment: @symplectomorphic - You also can't really even do a conjunction of a finite number of cases unless you know exactly what cases there are. With predicate logic, on the other hand, I can state that all the computers are working without knowing whether MATH3 is the only such computer.

Comment: @Malice Vidrine: I said as much in parentheses: "supposing you had this extra information."

Comment: I figured. I just wanted to de-parenthetical it to make it clearer to the OP why even a finite number of cases can challenge the expressive power of propositional logic.

Answer (score 4):

If your domain is finite, then yes, we *could* do everything in propositional logic instead of predicate logic, but:

1. Not every domain is finite (think numbers, sets, graphs, etc.)
2. Even if the domain is finite, then:

2a. We may not know all of its elements (think all people in the world)

2b. There are just too many elements in the domain for this to be practical, efficient, or convenient

Comment: The example given consists of a finite domain, because the the number of computers is finite.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of propositional logic, the statement:

> “Every computer connected to the university network is functioning properly.”

can be symbolized only as $p$.

The statement:  “(The computer) MATH3 is functioning properly" can be symbolized with $q$.

No propositional inference can licenses us to infer $q$ from $p$.

---

In order to express the logical relation between the two, we need *predicate logic*.

We have to symbolize the first statement as:

> $\forall x ( \text {Computer}(x) \to \text {Funct_prop}(x))$.

Now, using the auxiliary statement: $\text {Computer(MATH3)}$, we can apply [Universal instantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation) to derive:

> $\text {Computer(MATH3)} \to \text {Funct_prop(MATH3)}$

and conclude by [Modus Ponens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens) with: $\text {Funct_prop(MATH3)}$.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The first sentence can in fact be symbolized as the conjunction of a finite number of sentences (for certainly there are a finite number of computers connected to the network), one of which is $q$. The deeper point, of course, is that this trick is not available in general: the paragraph the OP quotes gives a bad example.

Comment: @symplectomorphic - nowhere in the example it is assumed that there is only a *finite* number of computer in the univer(sity).

Comment: Yes, but you've glossed over the fact that we can choose how to schematize natural language sentences. There is no "rule" that forces us to ignore the semantic meaning of the sentence when we schematize; and in this case, if we are intent on using propositional logic, we can, depending on our goals in regimenting the sentence into a logical formalism.

Comment: @symplectomorphic - you can use a better example: consider "every man is mortal". Of course we have today a finite number of men, and in every future moment this will be so. But we cannot list the names of the men that will be born tomorrow, and still the general assertion about all men holds.

Comment: Yes, that is right (and my comment on the OP gives another example), but the point I'm raising is that you didn't respond to the OP's main idea. In fact, *in some cases*, given *enough relevant information*, universally quantified sentences can indeed be formalized in propositional logic as conjunctions. It all depends on what one wishes to do with the formalization. It is not a purely logical question what features of the sentence one wishes to capture in the formalization.

Answer (score 2):

> > No rules of propositional logic allow us to conclude the truth of the statement “MATH3 is functioning properly",where MATH3 is one of the computers connected to the university network.
>
> This is supposed to illustrate the motivation for predicate logic.
>
> *However,we can interpret the given statement as the conjunction of statements of the form "MATHx is connected to the university network and is working properly"*.

Yes, indeed, and this is the *first step* in moving from propositional logic to predicate logic.

You are no longer discussing a *single* statement about a *single* subject —a proposition—, rather you have moved to discussing a *conjunction* of *similar* statements about *subjects* that belong to a *collection*.

That is on the path to developing quantfied predicate statements.   Next is to move from discussing specific collections, to general collections, and formalise the rules of logic to manage the discussions.

Answer (score 1):

If nullary relation symbols are allowed, then restricting the signature of a first-order language to nullary relation symbols results in propositional logic.  Thinking of propositional logic as the result of restricting the signature to nullary relation symbols shows how in propositional logic we are constrained in referring to the elements of the domain in the logic.

Specifically, let $\mathcal{L}_0$ be our restricted signature, and let $D$ be the domain of an $\mathcal{L}_0$-structure.  Since $D^0 = \{\emptyset\}$, each relation symbol may only be interpreted as $\emptyset$ (always false) or $D^0$ (always true) regardless of $D$.  There are no terms in formulae; hence there is no use for quantifiers.

These restrictions prevent us from expressing many interesting statements about integers or humans, and result in large formulae in many other instances.  It should be noted, though, that there are practical cases in which the "propositional approach" is surprisingly efficient: not in terms of the size of the formulae, but in terms of the time needed to decide satisfiability.

Answer (score 0):

You can express a conjunction such as the following:

"Math1 is connected and working properly AND Math2 is connected and working properly AND ... MathX is connected and working properly",

in propositional logic.  However, this does not say that "Every computer connected to the university network is functioning properly." as you have claimed.  Why?  Because there does not exist any guarantee that the conjunction above covers every computer in the network.  You would at least need some clause that says something like "and the only computers on the network are math1, ... mathX".

Unfortunately though, this doesn't answer your question, but it seems too long for a comment, so I'll leave it as a so-called "answer".